# React Native Fullscreen

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create a simple react native application. I need to run the app in fullscreen mode. Is there a way to do this?

I need to remove/hide the bottom buttons. 
I am doing this for Android devices.

```
|---------------|
|               |
|    screen     |
|               |
-----------------
|  <|   O  [ ]  |     <--- I need to remove these buttons!
-----------------
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

React Native doesn't provide a way to hide the android navigation bar directly, you would have to create a [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) that use the [Android Immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) introduced in Android 4.4 or use an existing module that do just that, and I found only one: [react-native-full-screen](https://github.com/Anthonyzou/react-native-full-screen)

Comment: @YthaloRossy Did you find my answer helpful? Thanks

Comment: Hi @YthaloRossy, I am glad you found my answer helpful :) If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark or up-voting it (once you have enough reputation to do so). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I tried but this is a prototype. The main feature is a **toggle between fullscreen and normal screen**, but the user need to touch in the screen. In my case i need one feature that put the screen, all the time, in fullscreen. I will still searching a little more and if i find i will share here with you. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use navigators, I recommend this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/49544136/3332734

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Expo on your project then simply add the following to your `app.json` file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "visible": "immersive"
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The `app.json` file is your go-to place for configuring parts of your app that don't belong in code. It is located at the root of your project next to your package.json. For more info about the `app.json` file visit here:
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/

The `androidNavigationBar` is the configuration for the bottom navigation bar on Android. Setting it to `immersive` results in the navigation bar being hidden until the user swipes up from the edge where the navigation bar is hidden. For more info about the `androidNavigationBar` option visit here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#androidnavigationbar

Comment: this hides the top bar too. I mean the clock battery network ....

Answer (score 4):

In your project's android manifest file, select fullScreen activity.

Answer (score 4):

I created a package with fullscreen and more.

react-native-system-navigation-bar

**Install**

```
yarn add react-native-system-navigation-bar
```

or

```
npm install react-native-system-navigation-bar
```

**Links**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-navigation-bar

https://github.com/kadiraydinli/react-native-system-navigation-bar

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your Android Native `mainActivity`:

```
    /**
     * For fullscreen mode
     */
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }
```

Like this :

[image: Like this]

Comment: This makes it full screen though , i can still see some top bar with no content on xiaomi  ...