# Modal window in React Native with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` in React Native and I want, on startup, to determine if the user is logged in, and if he/she is already logged in, I want to open a modal window (full screen).

How is this best done? I cannot find anything in the react-navigation docs where a screen is conditionally shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you needs to change the `mode` from Navigation.

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MainStack,
    },
    MyModal: {
      screen: ModalScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);
```

You can [run this code here](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/full-screen-modal)

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

References:

- [Opening a full-screen modal](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal.html)
- [NavigatorConfig` props](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig)

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
const ModalNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    ModalScreen: { screen: ModalScreen },
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    headerMode: "none",
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

React has a Modal component that you can use to display a full-screen Modal. See the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

To display it conditionally if the user is logged in you can use the 'visible' property.
E.g. drop this on the screen that your app loads to:

```
<Modal
      animationType={"slide"}
      transparent={false}
      visible={this.state.userIsLoggedIn}
      >
```

Comment: How would this fit with a StackNavigator in React Navigation?

Comment: The react docs have an example that uses a modal mode in StackNavigator, have you looked through this? https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/NavigationPlayground