# react native truely full screen content for android

Tags: android, react-native, fullscreen, statusbar

I'm trying to make my View content take up the full height of the screen (including the status bar area) and produce true fullscreen content. Different from setting StatusBar background transparent where the icons are still visible.

[I want to see only the red background, no statusbar and no navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSn3W.png)

I've tried using leanback mode from react-native-system-navigation-bar, which is supposed to remove the status bar and navigation bar. But it removes to navigation bar but only make the status bar background black.

[leanback mode ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxRVx.png)

I've tried leanback mode on and StatusBar hidden. but it only removes the white status bar icons and leaves a black background.

[leanback mode ON & StatusBar.hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUbY7.png)

I've tried changing the background Color of the status bar and setting translucency but that goes away when in leanback mode and am left with black background.

Does anyone know how to create content truly full screen?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for Android's immersive mode?

You need to use a library to access that feature, the only one I can find was [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-immersive-mode), give it a try..

Also I think it's worth looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093675/react-native-fullscreen) question for answers that relate to yours